# Call a function automatically when any update occurs in database in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

Is there any way that i can call a function when any update, delete or create function executed in database. I have a Boolean variable which is true by default. When someone create update or delete an element from the database i want to set that boolean variable to false.
e.g my code is

```
<template name="questions">  
     {{#each question}}  
         <tr>
             <td>{{name}}</td>
             <td><<input type="button">Delete</button></td>
             <td><input type="button"Update</button></td>
         </tr>
     {{/each}}
</template>
```

I want if a Delete or Update action is successfully performed on these questions elements the boolean variable become false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a smart package to handle the part of firing a callback on insert/update/remove: https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

In this callback you could then change your Boolean value either by running an update or mutating the document/query.